# How to retrieve all AutoFac components of a certain type?

Tags: nhibernate, autofac

I'm writing an MVC 4 application that requires the use of multiple NHibernate Session Factories.  I'm registering these objects with AutoFac by name. In my global.asax, I need to retrieve all Session Factories and bind/unbind them to the CurrentSessionContext.

```
 protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (ISessionFactory sessionFactory in SessionFactories)
            {
                if (!CurrentSessionContext.HasBind(sessionFactory))
                {
                    CurrentSessionContext.Bind(sessionFactory.OpenSession());
                }
            }
        }

        protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (ISessionFactory sessionFactory in SessionFactories)
            {
                ISession session = CurrentSessionContext.Unbind(sessionFactory);
                session.Close();
                CurrentSessionContext.Unbind(sessionFactory);
            }
        }
```

I'm running into a problem retrieving my SessionFactories from AutoFac. Namely, when I try to retrieve them using the `Resolve` method I get an empty collection.  However, things work if I instead use the`ResolveNamed` method:

```
 SessionFactories =
                new List<ISessionFactory>
                    {
                        container.ResolveNamed<ISessionFactory>("DB1"),
                        container.ResolveNamed<ISessionFactory>("DB2")
                    };
```

While this works, it seems rather fragile (I must update this code if any Name changes, or I add/remove SessionFactories). Is there a way to retrieve all objects from AutoFac by type *that includes named instances*?

Comment: possible duplicate of [autofac: How to resolve collection of named types?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5779517/autofac-how-to-resolve-collection-of-named-types)

Comment: Not a duplicate.  The referenced question asks how to resolve named instances.  I'm asking how to resolve all instances by type, regardless of how they were registered with the container (name, key, anonymously)

Answer (score 1):

Use `Resolve<IEnumerable<ISessionFactory>>()`

See [Relationship Types](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/RelationshipTypes) for further info.

Comment: Huh, I didn't know that named registrations behaved this way. If you you do your regsitrations like `Named<X>("name").As<X>()` then my answer would work, but I don't know if that's acceptable in your situation.